# Prevent declaring empty array everytime i call the function

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
const someFunction = (dyanamic data) => {
    let dataArray = [];
    let dataObject = {
        name: `${dynamic data}`
    };
    dataArray.push(dataObject);
}

someFunction(dyanamic data);
```

now imagine someFunction is called on every button press lets say in react native,then dataArray will become empty everytime how can i prevent this.

Comment: you can make `dataArray` a global variable. If it is react, this might involve making it part of the state, or using a hook such as useRef

Comment: Take the array out of this function

Comment: Declare it as a global array. Take ``let dataArray = [];`` outside your function ``someFunction``.

Answer (score 0):

Your array should be global.

```
const someFunction = (dyanamic_data, dataArray) => {
    let dataObject = {
        name: `${dynamic data}`
    };
    dataArray.push(dataObject);
}
// declare your array
const dataArray = [];
// call your function
someFunction(dyanamic_data_1, dataArray); 
someFunction(dyanamic_data_2, dataArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 let dataArray = [];
    const someFunction = (dyanamic data) => {
        let dataObject = { name: `${dynamic data}` };
        dataArray.push(dataObject);
    }

    someFunction(dyanamic data);
```

Comment: you can use `const` for dataObject